# Passing a byte array from Java to C++ with JNI without copy

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I wanted to pass a large byte[] from Java to C++. I know that I could use Java ByteBuffers to share memory between C++ and Java as follows:

```
    ByteBuffer bb;
    bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(3);
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };
    bb.put(byteArray);
    modifyByteBuffer(bb); //native function
```

and access it in C++ through:

```
uint8_t *iBuf = (uint8_t*) env->GetDirectBufferAddress(buf1);
```

However, the `bb.put(byteArray)` operation, is a copy. If I use `ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray)`, then I can't access the byte array in the C++ side with `env->GetDirectBufferAddress`. How can I solve this dilemma and pass on a `byte[]` without needing to do a copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call:

```
GetPrimitiveArrayCritical
```

and

```
ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical
```

for references to the `byte[]`. Don't bother with the `ByteBuffer` at all.

Comment: I thought that the JVM decides to do a copy or not with "GetPrimitiveArrayCritical" isn't that the case?

Comment: The JVM reserves the right to copy, yes. It's never been observed to do so in practice by me.